# React native call a method of second compoent from first component

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I have 2 components LoginView and LoginLogic.

LoginView deals with UI and LoginLogic deals with computation.
I want to know how I can pass my email and password attributes to LoginLogic from LoginView.

Here is my code -

LoginView.js

```
onLoginPressed = () => {
        //Here I need to pass email and pwd to LoginLogic. There is a method by name loginUser that takes email and password as method parameters

    }

    render() {
        return (

                <View>

                    <TextInput onChangeText={(text) => this.setState({ email: text })}>
                    </TextInput>
                    <TextInput onChangeText={(text) => this.setState({ password: text })}>
                    </TextInput>
                    <TouchableHighlight onPress={this.onLoginPressed} style={styles.button}>
                        <Text style={styles.buttonText}>Login </Text>
                    </TouchableHighlight>
                </View>

        );
    }
```

How do I pass the email and password to LoginLogic.js upon `onLoginPressed()`?

Comment: is your `LoginLogic`  and `LoginView` are under same parent?

Comment: Can you try this... In your `LoginLogic`, update like `<LoginLogic emailAndName = "this.emailAndNameMethod"/>` and we will call `emailAndNameMethod` on your `onLoginPressed` like 
`onLoginPressed = () => {this.props.emailAndNameMethod(email, password);}` and in `LoginLogic` 
get the details like `emailAndNameMethod = (email, password) => {console.log(email);console.log(password);};`

Answer (score 0):

you could import your loginUser method in your LoginView.js and then call it in the onLoginPressed function.

```
import { loginUser  } from '../anypath/LoginLogic.js'; //up next to others imports

onLoginPressed = () => {
 const { password, email } = this.state
 loginUser(email, password);
}
```

but if your LoginLogic is a class component, than it should be thinked in another way. let know if that helps and give us more information about the LoginLogic.

try to lern more about redux. is very helpful for the appState, for dispatching actions.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should revise your app architecture. React gives you the component model in which (in my understanding) you should not separate computational and view components but rather keep components reusable and thus self-sufficient yet compact.

Also React relies on a hierarchy tree structure so you should always try to lower abstraction levels the further you go down the tree resp. go from general to specific - maybe keep your main app logic / state the highest possible up and pass down data via props to components that need it. If your app and state management becomes more complex start thinking of using Flux/Redux or the React Context API.

Maybe step back a bit and take another look at https://reactjs.org/docs/thinking-in-react.html